# Apache configurations to restrict requests with specific string in request URL

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I have one URL configured on Apache. Here is configuration

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.82:443>
        ServerName test.ex.com
        Header always set Strict-transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomain; preload"
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
        ProxyRequests On

        ProxyPass /cong http://192.168.4.185:8081/cong
        ProxyPassReverse /cong http://192.168.4.185:8081/cong

        ErrorLog logs/test.ex.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/test.ex.com-access_log common
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/*.ex.com/36287365__.ex.com.cert
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/*.ex.com/36287365__.ex.com.key
        Header add P3P "CP=\"NOI DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND OTC\""
</VirtualHost>
```

With above configurations, I am allowing all the request comes to https://test.ex.com/cong/. I want to restrict some specific request comes with string "getUserPattern" in request string like https://test.ex.com/cong/module/getUserPattern/final

Tried with `ProxyBlock getUserPattern` but didn't work. Is there any way/configuration to restrict such URLs at apache level only or redirect to https://test.ex.com/cong.

Comment: Do you want to block exactly the URI `/cong/module/getUserPattern/final` or any URL with `getUserPattern` string?

Comment: any URL with `getUserPattern` String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you probably want to disable forward (standard) proxy requests (Setting `ProxyRequests` to `Off` does not disable use of the `ProxyPass` directive):

```
ProxyRequests Off
```

If you want to redirect any request containing `getUserPattern` to `https://test.ex.com/cong`, add these two directives above your current ProxyPass rules:

```
RedirectMatch "getUserPattern" "https://test.ex.com/cong"
ProxyPassMatch "getUserPattern" !
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In existing configurations, I just added `RewriteEngine on` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /getUserPattern/` `RewriteRule (.*)$ https://test.ex.com/cong/` lines. I am testing different scenarios with this. Till now, it's working fine.

Comment: Yes, you can do something like that. RewriteRule is more powerful but also uses more resources so generally is recommended only if the purpose can not be achieved by other means.

Comment: OK. Probability of Request with such URL is very less in my case. But it's there. So resources not be the major concern. Thanks for your info.